# How to embed a PDF into a HTML page and have the PDF render the width of the browser

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, render

I have sort of a unique request from a client.  My HTML page will have a PDF embedded into it (like via an iframe or similar).  What I am really needing though is this.  If you navigate directly to a .pdf URL, the PDF renders in the browser full "browser screen", if that makes sense.  How can I emulate this behavior in an iframe (or something else that I might not have thought of)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com/examples/) javascript script to embed PDF into DIV element. Notice that embedding 2 or more PDF files may cause the browser to be irresponsive (especially if you have Adobe Reader as PDF plugin)